# C# can i keep the config section handlers in a different assembly?

Tags: .net, app-config, configurationsection

I have a console app client, which is calling a method on another assembly, this other assembly requires some configuration info to be initialized, can i keep the section handlers of such configs in the assembly itself? and not expose to the console app client?
If i could do so, then how should i go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

If by "not expose" you mean keeping configuration handler classes within the assembly, then sure. You can use `ConfigurationManager` within the library methods and keep everything internal. But keep in mind that you will need to define xml configuration in console client's app.config, not the library-specific config.